# Rails 3 - validate through few models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have 4 models: `SchoolClass`, `Timetable`, `Lesson`, `Reporting`:

```
#  class_code :string(255)
class SchoolClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timetables
end

class Timetable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school_class
  has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timetable
  has_one :reporting
end

# report_type  :string(255)
class Reporting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson

  validates :report_type,
              :presence  => true,
              :inclusion => { :in => %w(homework checkpoint)}
end
```

How can i validate that each `SchoolClass` can have only 1 `Reporting` with type "**checkpoint**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets super complicated because of the nesting associations.
I would start by using a custom validation method.

in the SchoolClass model:

```
validate :only_one_reporting_checkpoint
```

and then the method:

```
def only_one_reporting_checkpoint
  timetables = self.timetables
  reporting_checkpoint = nil
  timetables.each do |t|
    t.lessons.each do |l|
      reporting_checkpoint = true if l.reporting.report_type == "checkpoint"
    end
  end
  if reporting_checkpoint == true         
    errors.add(:reporting, "exception raised!")
  end
end
```

There, I think that does it. If I understand your problem correctly.